# How can i avoid an infinite loop in my useEffect?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm working in a functional component called TaskComponent, where i have this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getFilterTasks = () => {
      onSnapshot(q, (QuerySnapshot) => {
        QuerySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          filteredTasks.push(doc.data())
          console.log(filteredTasks);
        })
        setTasks(filteredTasks);
        })
      }
    
    getFilterTasks();

}, [])
```

In my component i have a Flatlist where tasks-state is my data for the Flatlist, so i want to render my component everytime tasks changes and it changes everytime i navigate from my TaskComponent to CategoryComponent and back to TaskComponent again, because the filtered tasks is different based on which category i select. The concept is illustrated in the following three picture:

[image]
[image]
[image]

And obviously adding ''tasks'' to my dependecy array doesn't work because of the infinite loop it will create because i'm calling setTasks in the useEffect as well.

So i'm not sure have i can solve this, is there a tricky way to solve this, do I have to rerender my component or something completely different?

Comment: Add tasks count to your dependency array.

Comment: You can solve this by many ways. Easy One with a flag refresh/setRefresh. Setting to true when you render a component and setting to false at the end of your useefect. Of course also add refresh as a dependency in your useEffect.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about "tasks count", is it a new useState variabel?

Comment: @pepinillo6969 Ah thanks, i'm not sure i have done it in the right way of what you mean, but i have posted it as an answer to my question. Does the method you describe requires a button to refresh or is there something I misunderstand?

Comment: Not being familiar with the onSnapShot API, it would seem this is a listener which you should clean up using a returned function from your useEffect hook ([see docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup)).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The question is solved now, i just added the item.id in the dependency array.

This is how i have done with the refresh/setRefresh state:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getFilterTasks = async() => {
    const q = query(collection(db, 'allTasks'), where('userID', '==', userID), where('categoryID', '==', item.id))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      filteredTasks.push(doc.data())
    })
    setTasks(filteredTasks)
    }

    getFilterTasks();

    setRefresh(false)
    console.log(refresh)

  }, [refresh])


  const handleRefresh = () => {
    setRefresh(true);
  }
```

I have added the: const [refresh, setRefresh] = useState(false);

And then i have a button that is connected to handleRefresh.

This works, but it is not a beautiful way to do it.

Comment: Better add condition like if(refresh){ your API request} inside your useEffect. And set refresh initial state to true. This way you save one useless API call when refresh is set back to false.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to know that useEffect combines componentDidMount, ComponentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount.

So, if you need it to **work just one time** when your component renders (**commponentDidMount Approach**):

- **Recommended if you're fetching data from API**
- **Your array of dependencies should be empty**

```js
useEffect( () => {
  set Your Logic here
  
}, [])
```

If you need to **keep watching changes** for some variables/ states (**ComponentDidUpdate Approach**):

- **Recommended If you want to update some parts of your component based on a variable that might change in run time**
- **Pass the variables that you want to watch in the array of dependencies**

```js
useEffect(()=>{

  set Your Logic here

},[yourDependencies])
```

Finally, if you want to run a **cleanup function when you're leaving a component** to prevent memory leaks and unwanted behaviors in your application (**componentWillUnmount Approach**):

```js
useEffect(()=>{
 
 set Your Logic here

  return () => {
            cleanup
        }

},[])
```